# Data is mismanaged when I scroll the UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller

I am using following code,in cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath method

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}
if(currentRow >=[finalArray count]) return cell;
// Configure the cell.


for(int ii=0;ii<[keys count];ii++){
NSString *no22=[dict objectForKey:[keys objectAtIndex:ii]];
no=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %"[keys objectAtIndex:ii],]  
}// end of the for loop


if(searching) 
    cell.text = [copyListOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
else {
cell.text=[finalArray objectAtIndex:currentRow];

    currentRow=currentRow+1;
}
    return cell;
```

}

I am getting strange behavior when I scroll the table data is completely mismanaged,please any suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is because you are reusing cells. You can reuse more type of cells.

And why you are doing `if(currentRow >=[finalArray count]) return cell;` this?

Comment: becasue if I am not using this value of currentRow increases from array and it gives exception

Comment: How can I detect that UITableView is scrolled to top so that I can reload data